# Initialization of a list of objects

Tags: java, list, object

I wrote this code

```
List<Object> result = null;

....
Object resultObject =method.invoke(o, "test", "test");
System.out.println(resultObject);
result.add(resultObject);
```

resultObject contain the result that I expect but the last line caus a NullpointerException.

Comment: your result is null, initialize your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Object> result = null;
```

The variable `result` now contains `null`.

```
result.add(resultObject);
```

You try to call `add()` on `result`, but as `result` is `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown instead.

You should create the list. Replace the first line with:

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

otherwise `result` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations prohibit null elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements. Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Attempting to query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception, or it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the former behavior and some will exhibit the latter.

```
List<YourObject> result = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
```

Reference Link : [Click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the list to null.In the problem line,you call a method on the list object which is currently null.This is bound to throw a NPE as u cant invoke methods on an object which isn't there.exceptions are static (s) or class members,where in any case the object is ignored and is considered a bad practice to do.eg this would work on a null object-
    `Object=null;`
`Object.clearData();`
where clearData() is a class member and shouldn't be called with an object reference.
So if new to Java learn this rule -you cannot call methods,or examine variables on an object that is initialized to  NULL.Null in java is just an empty reference and not an object.So it won't have any behavior.
Initialize it with a concrete type like `ArrayList<t>()`and it would work.